# Video animation in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to understand the animation added here in videos. What animation is happening here? I have understood that how is it adding animation to the video as a whole but I want to know how can we add animation to each image of video differently.

I have used the following code to pick an image and merge videos.

```
     class ImageVideoMakerController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            playPauseBtn.isHidden = true
            fromPlayVideo = true
            fromSave = false
            setUpInitialView()
        }
        func setUpInitialView(){
            setUpArrays()
            buildVideoFromImageArray()
            transitionScrollViewCreation()
            filterScrollContents()
        }

        @objc func filterActionTapped(sender:UIButton){
            fromFilter = true
            fromTransition = false
            if(sender.tag==0){
                player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                globalFilterName = "CISepiaTone"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)
            }else if(sender.tag==1){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectChrome"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)

            }else if(sender.tag==2){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName = "CIPhotoEffectTransfer"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)                
            }else if(sender.tag==3){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectTonal"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)                    
            }else if(sender.tag==4){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectProcess"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)
                 }else if(sender.tag==5){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectNoir"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)
            }else if(sender.tag==6){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectInstant"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)
            }
            else if(sender.tag==7){
                 player.pause()
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

                globalFilterName =  "CIPhotoEffectFade"
                applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied: globalFilterName!)
            }
        }
        func applyFilter(globalFilterToBeApplied:String){
            let filter = CIFilter(name: globalFilterToBeApplied)!
            let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
                let source = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
                filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                let output = filter.outputImage!.cropped(to: request.sourceImage.extent)
                request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
            })
            globalrVideoComposition = composition
          self.playVideoInPlayer(animatedVideoURL:self.globalVideoURL as URL)        }

        func playVideoInPlayer(animatedVideoURL:URL){
            if(globalFilterName != nil){
                self.asset = AVAsset.init(url:animatedVideoURL as URL)
                let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset:self.asset);
                newPlayerItem.videoComposition=globalrVideoComposition
                self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem:newPlayerItem)
            }else{
                let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url:animatedVideoURL)
                self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem:newPlayerItem)
            }

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishedPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object:nil)
            self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player:self.player)
            let width: CGFloat = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.width
            let height: CGFloat = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.height
            self.playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0, width: width, height: height)
            self.playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            self.videoContainerView.layer.addSublayer( self.playerLayer)

            self.playPauseBtn.isHidden = false

            self.playPauseBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named:"pause"), for:.normal)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for:self.view, animated:true)
                self.player.play()
            }

        }
            func exportVideoWithAnimation() {
                let composition = AVMutableComposition()
                    let track =  self.asset?.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)
                let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = track![0] as AVAssetTrack
                    let timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, (self.asset?.duration)!)

                let compositionVideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

                do {
                    try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timerange, of: videoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                    compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                //if your video has sound, you don’t need to check this
                    if self.audioIsEnabled {
                    let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

                        for audioTrack in (self.asset?.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio))! {
                        do {
                            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }

                let size = videoTrack.naturalSize

                let videolayer = CALayer()
                videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

                let parentlayer = CALayer()
                parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
                parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)                
                var time = [0.00001, 3, 6, 9, 12] //I used this time array to determine the start time of a frame animation. Each frame will stay for 3 secs, thats why their difference is 3
                    var imgarray = self.selectedImageArray

                    for image in 0..<self.selectedImageArray.count {


                        let nextPhoto = imgarray[image]

                        let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextPhoto.size.width
                        let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextPhoto.size.height
                        let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
                        let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextPhoto.size.width * aspectRatio, height: nextPhoto.size.height * aspectRatio)
                        let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                        let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
                        let blackLayer = CALayer()
                        ///#7. opacity(1->0)(top->bottom)///
                        //#3. top->bottom///
                        //MARK:- Animations==================================
                        ///#1. left->right///
                        if(self.globalSelectedTransitionTag == 0){

                            blackLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -videoTrack.naturalSize.width, y: 0, width: videoTrack.naturalSize.width, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
                            blackLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

                            let imageLayer = CALayer()
                            imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
                            imageLayer.contents = imgarray[image].cgImage
                            blackLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)


                            let animation = CABasicAnimation()
                            animation.keyPath = "position.x"
                            animation.fromValue = -videoTrack.naturalSize.width
                            animation.toValue = 5 * (videoTrack.naturalSize.width)
                            animation.duration = 5
                            animation.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(time[image])
                            animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                            blackLayer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")
                        }
                        parentlayer.addSublayer(blackLayer)
                    }
                let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
                layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
                layercomposition.renderSize = size

                layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)
                let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
                instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration)
                let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack
                let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)
                instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
                layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]
                if(fromTransition){
                self.globalrVideoComposition = layercomposition
                }
                let animatedVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/video2.mp4")
                    self.removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: animatedVideoURL)

                guard let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
                    assetExport.videoComposition = self.globalrVideoComposition
                assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
                assetExport.outputURL = animatedVideoURL as URL
                print("****** animatedVideoURL *****",animatedVideoURL)
                assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                    switch assetExport.status{
                    case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                        print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                        print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
                    default:
                        print("Exported")

                        if(self.fromPlayVideo){
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.globalVideoURL = animatedVideoURL; self.playVideoInPlayer(animatedVideoURL: animatedVideoURL as URL)
                                 }
                        }else if(self.fromSave){

                            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: animatedVideoURL as URL)
}) { saved, error in

                                }

                                if saved {


                                }else{

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            //MARK:- Make ScrollViews   
            @objc func transitionTapped(sender:UIButton){
                self.fromSave = false
                self.fromPlayVideo = true
                self.playPauseBtn.isHidden = true

                self.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

             globalSelectedTransitionTag = sender.tag
            exportVideoWithAnimation()

         }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken the animation there is nothing more than an opacity animation.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
```

it "fades in" over a few seconds.

It looks like there's also a "scale animation" which just scales it up in size.

1. The code you give is badly written and messy, so I would forget about it and not look at it, as a beginner.
2. As a beginner, I would not jump in to "video .. and animations too!" at first.

Just try making some "simple" animations in your app.  A good thing to start with is something that "slides on and off the screen" or perhaps just fades in and out.  (So, try doing those things to a button or the like.)